# How can I start redis queue worker without command line interface?

Tags: python, redis, task-queue

I use this tool http://python-rq.org/

I have a flask app, but I could not find the way to start rq worker other than with rq cli, e.g. `$ rq worker`
I need to have the worker running all the time, how can I make it running as a service? I need the service to start up on boot also.

Answer (score 1):

You should investigate some supervisor program to control your rq worker. Take a look at [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) or systemd. I personally use supervisord and it's pretty popular in the Python community.

This is how any supervisor program works (not to be confused with supervisord): the supervisor itself is a service (controlled by another service! e.g., systemd, initd, etc) and it runs programs specified in its configuration file. If a program exits or has issues, the supervisor will respawn it.

If you were in the docker ecosystem, it'd be simpler because docker can be your supervisor.

Comment: thank you, I tried supervisor out, seems he has some problems launching python3 commands from python2, because itself it is based on python2. Thanks for idea!

Answer (score 0):

Multiple options :

For dev purpose, I recommand a docker container (https://docker.com). For production purpose, the cleanest way is : use the packaged version for your system (assuming you're using a GNU/Linux box) along with a dedicated systemd unit.

For example, on Debian :

```
apt-get update && apt-get install redis
```

Then edit redis.conf, and start it :

```
systemctl start redis
```

Enable it (== start redis during startup)

```
systemctl enable redis
```

Comment: The question is about the rq worker, not redis itsel, it sounds like Redis isn't the problem.